# Angular 13 clean install wouldn't work with web3.js

Tags: angular, web3js

I cannot make use of the web3 package at all, I'm getting errors in the polyfills.ts file and the given instructions from the [Web3Js GitHub](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/tree/v1.7.0#readme) aren't working for me

The steps to replicate this:
Started a new project with angular cli:

```
ng new test-app
```

Then resumed installing web3 and it's dependencies according to their github instructions

```
npm install web3
npm install --save-dev crypto-browserify stream-browserify assert stream-http https-browserify os-browserify
```

After this I have added an additional property (paths) to the tsconfig.json as such:

```
"paths" : {
    "crypto": ["./node_modules/crypto-browserify"],
    "stream": ["./node_modules/stream-browserify"],
    "assert": ["./node_modules/assert"],
    "http": ["./node_modules/stream-http"],
    "https": ["./node_modules/https-browserify"],
    "os": ["./node_modules/os-browserify"],
}
```

And finally added this into the `polyfills.ts` file

```
(window as any).global = window;
global.Buffer = Buffer;
global.process = {
    env: { DEBUG: undefined },
    version: '',
    nextTick: require('next-tick')
} as any;
```

Unfortunately those changes aren't working because I'm getting build errors at polyfills.ts, more specifically the following:

> Cannot find name 'global'.

> Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node` and then add 'node' to the types field in your tsconfig.

Those additions in the polyfills.ts file are necessary because otherwise I'd get this error:

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
> - install 'url'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

Upon debugging I can see that the `global` variable is indeed undefined.
I have tried to trick it into declaring it (as found around on some other Stack Overflow threads) at func level (declare global as any, declare require as any) but that would lead me to the upper error.

1. Npm version - 8.5.0
2. node.js version - 17.5.0
3. web3 npm package version - ^1.7.0

After more trial and error I have been able to build and serve properly with all the upper changes but upon any attempt to use web3 in my code, i get the following:

```
./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:43:10-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'D:\Work\Tutorials\CryptoZombies\crypto-zombies-angular\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'
```

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
> - install 'url'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

After installing url and xhr2-cookies I was able to run it (even though I'm getting this warning:

> CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So today I had the same problem and I found this solution on this github repository: https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js on the readme under "Web3 and Angular".

It's basically the same solution like yours with the only change that you have to paste this into your polyfills.ts file instead:

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

(window as any).global = window;
global.Buffer = Buffer;
global.process = {
    env: { DEBUG: undefined },
    version: '',
    nextTick: require('next-tick')
} as any;
```

With that I didn't have to install any extra dependencies (xhr2-cookies in your case).

Answer (score 0):

I have installed 2 antique packages (url and xhr2-cookies) and made it work, although it feels wrong and there has to be a more cleaner way since I'm getting a warning about common js dependencies being used and possibly making my bundle bigger.